# Fail to upload gpx to Garmin GPS (GPSmap 60CSx) from Linux using gpsbabel CLI

Tags: gpx, garmin, gpsbabel

I am trying to upload some gpx data (GPX XML format) to a Garmin GPSmap 60CSx unit using the `gpsbabel` (v.1.5.4) command line interface for Linux (Ubuntu 18.04).

I followed instructions from the gpsbabel website https://www.gpsbabel.org/htmldoc-development/fmt_garmin.html. Specifically, to test the connectivity I tried to download data from the GPS device into a gpx file, using the command

```
gpsbabel -i garmin -f usb: -o gpx -F blah.gpx
```

This worked fine so I then tried to do the opposite using the command

```
gpsbabel -D1 -i gpx -f Olympos.gpx -o garmin -F usb:
```

but no tracks and/or waypoints appeared in the unit after the transfer was complete. The USB default unit is identified correctly

```
gpsbabel -o garmin -F usb:-1
```

returned

```
0 3352480812 292 GPSMap60CSX Software Version 4.00
```

then using `usb:0` or `usb:` as output device and debug output enabled in command line I see no error :

```
GPSBabel Version: 1.5.4 
options: module/option=value: gpx/snlen="32" (=default)
Unit:   GPSMap60CSX Software Version 4.00
ID: 292
Version:    4.00
Capability A10:
Capability A100: D110
Capability A201: D202 D110 D210
Capability A301: D312 D302
Capability A400: D110
Capability A500: D501
Capability A600: D600
Capability A601: D601
Capability A700: D700
Capability A800: D800
Capability A801: D801
Capability A900:
Capability A902:
Capability A903:
Capability A904:
Capability A905: D900
Capability A907: D907 D908 D909 D910
Capability A908: D911
Capability A914:
Capability A916:
Capability A917: D917
Capability A918: D918
Capability A1010:
Capability A1011:
Link_type 1  Device_command 0
Waypoint: Transfer 100 Type 110
Route:    Transfer 201 Header 202 Type 110
Track:    Transfer 301 Type 302
Waypoint type: 110
Chosen waypoint length 14
cet_util: Converting from "UTF-8" to "US-ASCII", done.
```

what could be wrong ?
Is transferring to the device supported ?

Comment: Hi would be great to know if you had any success resolving this. Suffering same issue :-(

Comment: Hi @John yes the problem was that I did not use the correct arguments. at least one of "-w" [on by default], "-r", "-t" must be present to process the corresponding information. Do be careful , sometimes waypoint info may be embedded in tracks and so only "-t" would actually do the copy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented by the asker:

> ... the problem was that I did not use the correct arguments. at least
> one of "-w" [on by default], "-r", "-t" must be present to process the
> corresponding information. Do be careful , sometimes waypoint info may
> be embedded in tracks and so only "-t" would actually do the copy.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo usermod -a -G dialout $USER`

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. We are looking for Answers which not only tell what so do, but explain *why*, citing documentation and/or giving a justification on why the comma and should be used.